# OnEndReached fired continuously due to data less than a page

Tags: react-native, fetch, react-native-flatlist

My onEndReachedThreshold is set to 1. One of the user only has 1 item in cart. So the getSavedItem() keeps getting called. What would be the right way to handle this?

One way I thought was to have a flag that would be set to "NoMoreRequest" when server returns an empty list. but this does not seem to be the right way since the user can add more item to the cart and the flat list would still not make more request to update data.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1}}>
                        <FlatList
                            data={this.state.dataSource}
                            onEndReached = {() => this.getSavedItem()}
                            onEndReachedThreshold={1}
                            renderItem={this._renderItem}
                            ListFooterComponent={()=>(this.state.loading) ? <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="gray"/> : null}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item._id}
                        />
                </View>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Chetan: If you got any solution, could you please post here.

Comment: did someone ever found a solution for this?